# Acctivity is in portrait mode but it finds fragments in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-orientation, android-configchanges

I have 2 different layouts for portrait and landscape mode:

`layout\activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And `layout-land\activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentorientationchangetest.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentorientationchangetest.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I add Fragment1 in onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, fragment1, "tag1").commit();
        }
    }
```

In Fragment1 there is a button that when is pressed a callback is sent to Activity. Here is callback in MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void OnButtonClick() {

        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2) == null) {
            Log.d("mytag", "one pane");
        }else{
            Log.d("mytag", "two pane");
        }
    }
```

When I start the program in portrait and press the button "one pane" is printed on logcat.

**But when I rotate to landscape and immediately rotate to portrait and then press the button "two pane" is printed in logcat. Why this happens?**

Comment: Do you actually see the second fragment - or is it possible it just isn't being destroyed and removed from FragmentManager during orientation changes?

Comment: No when I return to portrait I didn't see second fragment but it seems that second fragment exists yet in fragment manager.